# Logo 'sticking' to my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have been assigned a small HTML project, and I am stumped with the relationship between the logo, and the navigation bar.
The logo *should* have its own position, but it seems to be sticking to the navigation bar, whatever fix I try to apply.

I have attempted un-nesting the `div`, and also using it as a standalone `div` without the `.body >`, but it just doesn't want to un-stick from the navigation bar.

I have created a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gKFEL/), but it still doesn't really show the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "un-stick?" Where would you like it to appear?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks If I move the navigation bar, the logo moves with it, although it is not supposed to. The logo needs to be static, and not move when the navigation bar is moved.

Comment: Static keeps it fixed relative to the page. Fixed keeps it fixed relative to the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to

```
body > .logo {
position:fixed;
margin-top:-140px;
width:310px;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/maxzeroedge/gKFEL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

See the update now, problem was in positioning,

```
body > .navbar {
    position:inherit;
    background-color:#CCCC99;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}

body > .logo {

    width:310px;
    margin:20px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gKFEL/1/